# how do I send video attachment with android

Tags: android, image, video, android-intent, arrays

I have been inching forward on this problem. Following is the latest state.

I have an app that allows one user to send attachment to another user.

Here is the anatomy:

**To get the attachment to send, the following code is used:**

```
public void onGetAttachmentClicked(View view) {
        Intent attachment = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        attachment.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(attachment, "Attachment"),
                ATTACHMENT_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

….

//inside onActivityResult
if (requestCode == ATTACHMENT_REQUEST_CODE) {
            mAttachmentUri = data.getData();
        }

….
//inside do in background, I convert uri to byte[] which I then send to the blobstore
```

**Problem**

No matter which method I use to convert the uri to a byte array, I get the same error log

```
03-13 08:15:24.753: W/dalvikvm(9451): threadid=21: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d9a2a0)
03-13 08:15:24.824: E/AndroidRuntime(9451): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
03-13 08:15:24.824: E/AndroidRuntime(9451): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-13 08:15:24.824: E/AndroidRuntime(9451):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
03-13 08:15:24.824: E/AndroidRuntime(9451):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
```

Not much there. So I use debugger to step through, and here is what I found. When I use the following method, the error occurs in the while-loop after some number of iterations

```
public static byte[] uriToByteArray(Uri uri, Context context) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    // this dynamically extends to take the bytes you read
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    // this is storage overwritten on each iteration with bytes
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // we need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the byteBuffer
    int len = 0;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    // and then we can return your byte array.
    return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
}
```

If I use apache common, the code still fails during the conversion and with the same error

```
context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
byte[] attachmentBites = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
```

**Note:**

If the attachment is an image, everything works fine -- the exact same code. But if the attachment is a video, then I get the error. Also, for the test, I shoot the video with my phone's camcorder.

Comment: There should be more to the stack trace than what you have. Also, bear in mind that unless the video is very very short (e.g., a few seconds), you have nowhere enough heap space to load it all into memory.

Comment: @CommonsWare : wow! this is enlightening. I will do some experimentations. In the mean time I have to ask. 1) How do people send video attachments? 2) the error trace is what you see, is there something I can do to see more of the error from the trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do people send video attachments?

Ideally, by streaming. Read from the file and write to the network. It'll be similar code to what you're using, but some other form of `OutputStream` that you get from your `HttpURLConnection` or whatever.

> the error trace is what you see, is there something I can do to see more of the error from the trace?

There is usually a second stanza, listing the "Caused by" exception. If you aren't getting that, I have no good explanation for that behavior, but there's nothing you can do to obtain it if it is not already there, other than perhaps putting your own `try`/`catch` block around your stuff in `doInBackground()`.

Comment: This is interesting, I just tried sending the same video file with Gmail as an attachment. Gmail did fine. It shows my attachment as `CAM00366.mp4`. Thanks for the help. Now I have to go research how to stream a video from an android device to the blobstore.